# How to name a file from user input in python

Tags: python, file

I am very new to programming and I am trying to create a file of the user's data. I know how to collect the data and write it to a text file but I would like to name each file independently to the user's surname. Here's what I have so far:

```
fname=raw_input('Competitor forename : ')
sname=raw_input('Competitor surname : ')
email=raw_input('Email address : ')
phone=int(raw_input('Phone : '))
enter=raw_input('Have you already completed any games? (Yes/No) : ')
if enter=='yes':
    dcurrent=raw_input('Please tell us your current division : ')
    pcurrent=int(raw_input('Please tell us your current points : '))
    print'Thank you'

else:
    print'Welcome to the staff and postgraduate squash league'

d=open(fname,'w')
d.write(fname)
d.write(sname)
d.write(email)
d.close()
```

This code returns an error message when I attempt to create the file. All other attempts have resulted in a txt file simply named (sname).

Please help!

Comment: hi!  what's the error?

Comment: Running this code as you pasted it does not generate any errors (aside from picking a phonenumber that has letters in it). Is this the actual code you are running?

Answer (score 0):

Your question:

> I know how to collect the data and write it to a text file but I would
>   like to name each file independently to the user's **surname**.

You are currently using user's first name to create a file. The user's first name is stored in `fname`. Later you are creating a file with the value stored in `fname` as:

```
d=open(fname,'w')
```

If you want to create a file with a name that is user's **surname** then you have to use `sname` as shown below because it contains user's surname:

```
  d=open(sname,'w')
```

I hope this is want you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your codes and works fine. I didn't take any error messages. But I think if you want to collect more than one person's data you must open file as "a". And append "\n" end of the file. If I were you I use this code replace yours;

```
fname=raw_input('Competitor forename : ')
sname=raw_input('Competitor surname : ')
email=raw_input('Email address : ')
phone=int(raw_input('Phone : '))
enter=raw_input('Have you already completed any games? (Yes/No) : ')
if enter=='yes':
    dcurrent=raw_input('Please tell us your current division : ')
    pcurrent=int(raw_input('Please tell us your current points : '))
    print'Thank you'

else:
    print'Welcome to the staff and postgraduate squash league'

userInformation = fname + " " + sname + " " + email

d=open(fname,'a')
d.write(userInformation+"\n")
d.close()
```